# En España, ¿el Gobierno usa "tú" o "usted"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, españa, formalidad

Mi experiencia indica que en México se usa "usted", pero sé que en España quizás son un poco menos formales.

Tengo que traducir una carta de la Seguridad Social de EE.UU. en frases dirigidas a mí, ¿sería mejor utilizar "tú" o "usted"?

Comment: En este caso. *Usted*

Comment: Después de "quizás," el subjuntivo es mejor.  "El gobierno" no es una oficina particular.  No es título, sino el gobierno en general.  No merece mayúscula, como "estado" por "guifa" abajo.  Con "se usa" (singular), no se debe decir "son" (plural).  Y en México, es MUY común de poner el verbo primero en preguntas.

Comment: In other words, please let native speakers do this sort of editing.  I am not a native speaker, but I've been hearing, reading, and speaking Spanish for decades.  No doubt I make plenty of mistakes, but I also have SOME instinct for what sounds right.  "se usa" is also the usual way for what is an indefinite "they" in English.  As in "Se habla español" in the windows of so many stores.

Comment: Seamos claros. ¿ Lo que necesitas saber es si la carta se dirige a ti o a usted? ¿O como dirigirte tu a ellos?

Comment: Cuando te dirjes a una organización del tipo que sea. Para ti son "ellos". Y como persona educada que eres, usarás la forma "ustedes". Mantén las distancias, no se trata de formalidad solamente, sino de respeto hacia ellos y hacía ti.

Comment: @WGroleau _Estado_ and _Gobierno_ are capitalised when referring to them as institutions. Impersonal  _se_ is perfectly fine, but if you are asking if the Government uses something, there is no point in using an impersonal form, i.e. _Se usa el Gobierno_ — use either _se usa en el Gobierno_ or _usa el Gobierno_.

Comment: Ante la duda: _Usted_. Siempre es mejor pasarse de educado que lo contrario. En general, empieza las conversaciones con _usted_. Si la otra persona prefiere que le trates de _tú_, te lo dirá.  Y si no, puedes preguntar _te puedo tutear?_

Comment: On _government_ websites in Spain, Mexico, and other Spanish-speaking countries, it is sometimes capitalized and sometimes not.  But the Academy leans toward capitalizing: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=gobierno  For now, I stand by the rest of my comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para cualquier correspondencia formal, el estado español usará solo usted (además, usará el tratamiento «don» o «doña» para todos).

Es posible encontrar ejemplos del tuteo en, por ejemplo, campañas de publicidad para algún u otro programa, servicio, o evento.  Pero el ejemplo que das de una carta de Seguridad Social, definitivamente tendrá un tratamiento muy formal.

Comment: Sí, yo añadiría que para cualquier escrito legal y a cualquier institución estatal, incluso hacia un cliente si no se trata de publicidad como bien dices, siempre muy formal, por supuesto de usted.

Answer (score 4):

Para comunicaciones oficiales dirigidas a una persona concreta, el Gobierno **siempre** utilizará tratamientos formales ('usted'), nunca "tú".

Sólo en comunicaciones dirigidas al público en general (campañas informativas o divulgativas, peticiones de voto) a veces utiliza un tono informal y trata de 'tú'.

Comment: Resulta muy rudo usar "vos"? Creía que en España sólo parece antiguo.

Comment: La pregunta es cuál se usa el gobierno para escribir a mí.  La respuesta me parece "usted."

Comment: @WGroleau: sorry, I misunderstood thee question. I modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: @michau efectivamente. _Vos_ queda muy antiguo. No se usa en comunicaciones con el gobierno